# Padrino multilpe url for one route code

Tags: ruby, sinatra, padrino

I would like to handle multiple URLs with one route code.

I am trying something like this:

```
get '/company', '/about' do 
  ...
end
```

but it does not work. For `/company`, I get 200, but for `/about`, I get 404.

Is there such way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route file is a ruby file. You can do this with a simple loop:

```
['/company', '/about'].each do |route|
  get route do
    # ...
  end
end
```

From [the source code](https://github.com/padrino/padrino-framework/blob/f7d6950bc71f3b9578857c52714b1f20577205b1/padrino-core/lib/padrino-core/application/routing.rb#L356-L362):

```
def get(path, *args, &block)
  conditions = @conditions.dup
  route('GET', path, *args, &block)

  @conditions = conditions
  route('HEAD', path, *args, &block)
end
```

You can see that the `get` method only takes a single path.

Comment: Great this is working thanks, I was trying about sinatra style, but this is possibility too. Thank you

Comment: From the source code, it seems like path can also be a regexp, so `get %r{/(company|about)}` could work as well (haven't tried it).

Comment: (Haven't tried it either, but) don't forget to anchor the regex with `^ ... $`! Otherwise you could hijack all sorts of other routes, like `/not/about/the/company`.